# Can't find AddOverloads.xsl used in scott hanselman's script

Tags: c#

In
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/sandcastledoc.ps1.txt

the command 
XslTransform "$path\ProductionTransforms\AddOverloads.xsl" reflection.org

uses AddOverloads.xls but in last Sandcastle ProductionTransforms directory I can only find:

```
FixScriptSharp.xsl
MergeDuplicates.xsl
MergeHxF.xsl
ReflectionToCDocML.xsl
ReflectionToChmIndex.xsl
ReflectionToChmProject.xsl
ReflectionToManifest.xsl
TocToChmContents.xsl
TocToHxsContents.xsl
Vs2005TocToDsToc.xsl
AddFriendlyFilenames.xsl
AddGuidFilenames.xsl
AddXamlSyntaxData.xsl
ApplyPrototypeDocModel.xsl
ApplyVSDocModel.xsl
CreateHxC.xsl
CreateHxt.xsl
CreatePrototypeToc.xsl
CreateVSToc.xsl
DsManifestToManifest.xsl
DsTocToManifest.xsl
DsTocToSitemap.xsl
DsTocToToc.xsl
```

Which one should I use instead ?

I searched all over google. It's completely outdated back to 2007. Help on Help File really sucks, it's more difficult to build a documentation than to build a software !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen it claimed that AddOverloads.xml is obsolete ([here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/devdocs/thread/c259b49e-a196-4cff-8003-16a66886a36f))

I've had success with this alternative:

```
XslTransform /xsl:"$path\ProductionTransforms\ApplyVSDocModel.xsl" reflection.org /xsl:"$path\ProductionTransforms\AddFriendlyFilenames.xsl" /out:reflection.xml
```

There's a build file in the Sandcastle examples directory, and the equivalent line there (for vs2005) is:

```
XslTransform /xsl:"%DXROOT%\ProductionTransforms\ApplyVSDocModel.xsl" reflection.org /xsl:"%DXROOT%\ProductionTransforms\AddFriendlyFilenames.xsl" /out:reflection.xml /arg:IncludeAllMembersTopic=true /arg:IncludeInheritedOverloadTopics=true
```

HTH